# What would you say in the following situation?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice, american-english

You are at a picnic and you want to advise others to keep the place clean:

1- you had better clean the place before you leave
2- you must clean the place before you leave.

From what I know, ‘had better’ is used to imply the negative consequences that are most likely to happen if the advice isn't followed. And the modal ‘must’ is used when there is an obligation to do something. Can someone please tell me which is more accurate to be used in the context provided.

Comment: Since you say you want to ***advise*** them to clean up after themselves, you should probably use ***had better***, since that implies "recommendation". Saying ***must*** implies "obligation" (i.e. - you are ***ordering*** them to clear up).

Comment: It depends on how harsh you wish to be.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to *advise*, then say "You'd better ...".  If you want to *instruct* then you can say "You must ..." (or "You'll have to ...").

So both your examples are correct, but mean different things. I would only use "must" if I was in a position of authority. For example a teacher might tell her students that they "must do their homework", or when describing an external obligation "We must pick up the litter, it's the law!"

You would normally "tidy up" and not "clean" the picnic area, since a picnic is outdoors, and you can't clean the soil, but you can tidy up.